# Resize sidenav-content when toggle sidenav with Material Angular and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-material2

I'm using Angular, Angular-Material and Leaflet for creating a web that has A sidenav and a map.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="map-bar-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened class="nav">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content class="cmap">
        <app-map></app-map>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The problem is that when toggling the sidenav, the sidenav-content resized correctly, but the map inside does not, and the center of the map and its limits are offset. 
If you resize the window (opening the dev console also works) the map self center correctly and it works properly

I have recreated the problem on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u3mrrv

I have tried the autosize property of mat-sidenav-container but it didn't work.

You can notice the problem at the start the map is offset, if you resize the windows it will fix, then if you toggle the sidenav, it will get offset again.

I think the problem is that leaflet is not noticing that its container is changing of size and it's not updating when toggling the sidenav, just when resizing the windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the [leaflet.js documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-invalidatesize), you can call `map.invalidateSize()` to trigger a re-layout.

You should call this method whenever you open / close the sidenav component.

Comment: These seems to be exactly what I needed. Also I have to wait for the toggle animation to end to call for `map.invalidateSize()`. 
The final code `public toggle(): void {this.sidenav.toggle().then(() => {this.mapService.updateSize();});
  }`

Comment: Now I have another question, It's possible to know the new size of the sidenav-container without waiting for the toggle animation to end? I would like to have both animations running simultaneously instead of having to wait for the toggle to finish